# How to save sort stage of datagridview inform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a data grid view with all column have sorted =automation. 
My question: When I click on header and data in dgv will be sorted (ASC or DES). After that, I submit data and reload dgv --> don't save before stage. How I save sort stage(which column is sorted?).
Thanks in advance

Comment: `column = dataGridView1.SortedColumn` may be help you

Comment: It's works. Thank you so much. But how to set sort column? can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it may help you

```
DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;
ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction); //give column in place of newColumn for sorting
newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = null;
string colOrder = "";

// Call before reloading dgv
private void getSortedColumn()
{
    oldColumn = myDataGridView.SortedColumn;
    colOrder = myDataGridView.SortOrder.ToString();
}

//Call after reloading dgv
private void setSortedColumn()
{
    if (oldColumn != null)
    {
        if (colOrder == "Ascending")
        {
            myDataGridView.Sort(myDataGridView.Columns[oldColumn.Index], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
        else
        {
            myDataGridView.Sort(myDataGridView.Columns[oldColumn.Index], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        }

    }
}
```